# Accessing mysqli in .php file when using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

I am working on Laravel project where I need to get data from a db which is managed by a DB manager who uses only native php to communicate with it.

Before you suggest to write and eloquent query - please keep in mind the PHP native query is 250 lines long (it is a legacy system)

In order to make the connection with his DB he uses:

```
$conn1 = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database)
```

however I get the following error:

```
Class 'App\Helpers\mysqli' not found
```

I am aware what the error means - I am not sure how to add mysqli to Laravel and make it accessible in the code.

Anyone know a way around this ?

Comment: i am temped to voteclose this as a simple typographical error as i assume it is just as simple as using [PHP's default  namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) ? `$conn1 = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database)` -> `$conn1 = new \mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $database)`

Comment: There is no need to open a mysqli connection, you can use eloquent to run raw queries: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-methods

Comment: What you are looking for is not a mysqli connection but a pdo connection. And, 250 lines is *nothing*